# drop range partition in oracle between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

in Teradata you can do something like:

```
 DROP RANGE BETWEEN DATE FROM_DATE AND DATE TO_DATE, EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in Oracle? dropping a r

Comment: @BobJarvis, I think OP is asking for Oracle syntax, so Oracle tag is valid.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - yeah, I caught that and rolled back the change. My bad...

Comment: I see it now, I was too quick ;-)

Comment: Check this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/partitioning-management-range-list.html

Comment: @Stanislovas, that is a link to MySQL documentation ;-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DROP RANGE BETWEEN DATE FROM_DATE AND DATE TO_DATE, EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY;

In Oracle, you could use **PARTITION FOR** clause.

For example,

```
alter table table_name drop partition for (TO_DATE('some date','date format'))
```

I think one important thing needs to be kept in mind, you cannot drop the last partition, i.e. the first partition. It would throw an error:

> ORA-14758: Last partition in the range section cannot be dropped

Since you have not mentioned your exact Oracle version, I am sharing this 11gR2 documentation about [Dropping partitions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1007479).